# ¿Qué puede estar fallando en mi Request a un servicio SOAP?

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, wsdl

Quisiera consultar referente a llamada POST que hago a un web service en soap, que me devuelve un Bad Request.
Estas son las definiciones:

```html
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ServicioDummy" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IServicioDummy_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xs:element name="AsignarEquiposEnEvento">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="asignacionRequest" type="tns:AsignacionRequest" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:complexType name="AsignacionRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="IdEvento" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IdDummy" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Narracion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FechaDeEjecucion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AsignacionesPersonaA" type="tns:ArrayOfAsignacionPersonaA" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AsignacionesPersonaB" type="tns:ArrayOfAsignacionPersonaB" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Usuario" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAsignacionPersonaA">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="AsignacionPersonaA" nillable="true" type="tns:AsignacionPersonaA" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="AsignacionPersonaA">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Documento" type="tns:Documento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOb" type="tns:EQUIPOb" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="InicioMedidaCoercion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FinMedida" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="InicioColocacion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FinColocacion" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="Documento">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OrigenDocumento" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="NumeroDocumento" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TipoDocumento" type="tns:TipoDocumento" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="TipoDocumento">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="CEDULA_IDENTIDAD" />
          <xs:enumeration value="PASAPORTE" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:complexType name="EQUIPOb">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:extension base="tns:EquipoDummy">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TipoRastreador" type="tns:TipoRastreador" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="EquipoDummy">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="NumeroSerie" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Linea" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Estado" type="tns:Estado" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Observaciones" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="Estado">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="ACTIVO" />
          <xs:enumeration value="INACTIVO" />
          <xs:enumeration value="EXTRAVIADO" />
          <xs:enumeration value="DANADO" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:complexType name="EQUIPOC">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:extension base="tns:EquipoDummy" />
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="EQUIPOA">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:extension base="tns:EquipoDummy" />
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="TipoRastreador">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="RASTREADORA" />
          <xs:enumeration value="RASTREADORB" />
          <xs:enumeration value="RASTREADORC" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAsignacionPersonaB">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="AsignacionPersonaB" nillable="true" type="tns:AsignacionPersonaB" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="AsignacionPersonaB">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Documento" type="tns:Documento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOA" type="tns:EQUIPOA" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOb" type="tns:EQUIPOb" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOC" type="tns:EQUIPOC" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="InicioMedida" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FinMedida" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="InicioColocacion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FinColocacion" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="AsignarEquiposEnEventoResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AsignarEquiposEnEventoResult" type="tns:RespuestaAmpliacion" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:complexType name="RespuestaAmpliacion">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:extension base="tns:RespuestaGenerica">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="IdAmpliacion" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="RespuestaGenerica">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Respuesta" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Errores" type="tns:ArrayOfString" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="ModificarEquipo">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="modificacionRequest" type="tns:ModificacionRequest" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:complexType name="ModificacionRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="IdEvento" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IdDummy" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Narracion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Documento" type="tns:Documento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOA" type="tns:EQUIPOA" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOb" type="tns:EQUIPOb" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOC" type="tns:EQUIPOC" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FechaDeEjecucion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Usuario" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="ModificarEquipoResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ModificarEquipoResult" type="tns:RespuestaAmpliacion" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="AdicionarEvento">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="adicionarEventoRequest" type="tns:AdicionarEventoRequest" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:complexType name="AdicionarEventoRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="IdEvento" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IdDummy" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Narracion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FechaDeEjecucion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Documento" type="tns:Documento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TipoEvento" type="tns:TipoEvento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Usuario" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="TipoEvento">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="PROGRAMA_Dummy" />
          <xs:enumeration value="RESOLUCION" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="AdicionarEventoResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AdicionarEventoResult" type="tns:RespuestaAmpliacion" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ReasignarEquipo">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="reasignacionRequest" type="tns:ReasignacionRequest" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:complexType name="ReasignacionRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="IdEvento" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IdDummy" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Narracion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Documento" type="tns:Documento" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOA" type="tns:EQUIPOA" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOb" type="tns:EQUIPOb" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EQUIPOC" type="tns:EQUIPOC" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FechaDeEjecucion" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Usuario" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="ReasignarEquipoResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ReasignarEquipoResult" type="tns:RespuestaAmpliacion" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Ping">
        <xs:complexType/>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="PingResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PingResult" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_AsignarEquiposEnEvento_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:AsignarEquiposEnEvento" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_AsignarEquiposEnEvento_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:AsignarEquiposEnEventoResponse" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_ModificarEquipo_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ModificarEquipo" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_ModificarEquipo_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ModificarEquipoResponse" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_AdicionarEvento_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:AdicionarEvento" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_AdicionarEvento_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:AdicionarEventoResponse" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_ReasignarEquipo_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ReasignarEquipo" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_ReasignarEquipo_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ReasignarEquipoResponse" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_Ping_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:Ping" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IServicioDummy_Ping_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:PingResponse" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IServicioDummy">
    <wsdl:operation name="AsignarEquiposEnEvento">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IServicioDummy_AsignarEquiposEnEvento_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AsignarEquiposEnEvento" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IServicioDummy_AsignarEquiposEnEvento_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AsignarEquiposEnEventoResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ModificarEquipo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IServicioDummy_ModificarEquipo_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ModificarEquipo" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IServicioDummy_ModificarEquipo_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ModificarEquipoResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AdicionarEvento">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IServicioDummy_AdicionarEvento_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AdicionarEvento" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IServicioDummy_AdicionarEvento_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AdicionarEventoResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ReasignarEquipo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IServicioDummy_ReasignarEquipo_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ReasignarEquipo" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IServicioDummy_ReasignarEquipo_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ReasignarEquipoResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IServicioDummy_Ping_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/Ping" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IServicioDummy_Ping_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/PingResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServicioDummy" type="tns:IServicioDummy">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IServicioDummy_policy" />
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="AsignarEquiposEnEvento">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AsignarEquiposEnEvento" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ModificarEquipo">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ModificarEquipo" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AdicionarEvento">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/AdicionarEvento" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ReasignarEquipo">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/ReasignarEquipo" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IServicioDummy/Ping" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ServicioDummy">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IServicioDummy" name="WSHttpBinding_IServicioDummy">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost/tests/ServicioDummy.svc" />
      <wsa10:EnRASTREADORBintReference>
        <wsa10:Address>
          http://localhost/tests/ServicioDummy.svc
        </wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EnRASTREADORBintReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Este es el xml que estoy enviando:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:AsignarEquiposEnEvento>
      <tem:asignacionRequest>
        <tem:IdEvento>4629087</tem:IdEvento>
        <tem:IdDummy>123456</tem:IdDummy>
        <tem:Narracion>Se asigna equipo.</tem:Narracion>
        <tem:FechaDeEjecucion>2019-10-24</tem:FechaDeEjecucion>
        <tem:AsignacionesPersonaB>
          <tem:AsignacionPersonaB>
            <temocumento>
              <tem:OrigenDocumento>UY</tem:OrigenDocumento>
              <tem:NumeroDocumento>12121212</tem:NumeroDocumento>
              <tem:TipoDocumento>PASAPORTE</tem:TipoDocumento>
            </temocumento>
            <tem:EQUIPOb>
              <tem:NumeroSerie>35601234</tem:NumeroSerie>
              <tem:Linea>098123654</tem:Linea>
              <tem:Estado>ACTIVO</tem:Estado>
              <tem:Observaciones>Equipo en buen estado general</tem:Observaciones>
              <tem:TipoRastreador>RASTREADORB</tem:TipoRastreador>
            </tem:EQUIPOb>
            <tem:InicioColocacion>2019-09-01</tem:InicioColocacion>
            <tem:FinColocacion>2019-09-01</tem:FinColocacion>
          </tem:AsignacionPersonaB>
        </tem:AsignacionesPersonaB>
        <tem:Usuario>99999999</tem:Usuario>
      </tem:asignacionRequest>
    </tem:AsignarEquiposEnEvento>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Y este es el request que estoy realizando:

```js
let data = "\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soapenv:Envelope>\n    <soapenv:Header/>\n    <soapenv:Body>\n        <tem:AsignarEquiposEnEvento>\n            <tem:asignacionRequest>\n                <tem:IdEvento>4629087</tem:IdEvento>\n                <tem:IdDummy>123456</tem:IdDummy>\n                <tem:Narracion>Se asigna equipo.</tem:Narracion>\n                <tem:FechaDeEjecucion>2019-10-24</tem:FechaDeEjecucion>\n                <tem:AsignacionesPersonaB>\n                    <tem:AsignacionPersonaB>\n                        <temocumento>\n                            <tem:OrigenDocumento>UY</tem:OrigenDocumento>\n                            <tem:NumeroDocumento>12121212</tem:NumeroDocumento>\n                            <tem:TipoDocumento>CEDULA_IDENTIDAD</tem:TipoDocumento>\n                        </temocumento>\n                        <tem:EQUIPOb>\n                            <tem:NumeroSerie>35601234</tem:NumeroSerie>\n                            <tem:Linea>098123654</tem:Linea>\n                            <tem:Estado>ACTIVO</tem:Estado>\n                            <tem:Observaciones>Equipo en buen estado general</tem:Observaciones>\n                            <tem:TipoRastreador>RASTREADORB</tem:TipoRastreador>\n                        </tem:EQUIPOb>\n                        <tem:InicioColocacion>2019-09-01</tem:InicioColocacion>\n                        <tem:FinColocacion>2019-09-01</tem:FinColocacion>\n                    </tem:AsignacionPersonaB>\n                </tem:AsignacionesPersonaB>\n                <tem:Usuario>99999999</tem:Usuario>\n            </tem:asignacionRequest>\n        </tem:AsignarEquiposEnEvento>\n    </soapenv:Body>\n</soapenv:Envelope>\"";

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://servicio.com:4433/ServiciosTesting/ServicioPrueba.svc");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZGltb2U6RDFtMGUuL4Q==");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "94f8fdaa-d895-4289-9d62-a244f11757EQUIPOC");

xhr.send(data);
```

Esta es la primera vez que intento realizar un request a un servicio soap+xml y no tengo claro si esta es la forma en la que se debería hacer. Tengo la duda de si debería utilizar namespaces, y cuales deben de usarse, o cómo averiguarlo.
El resultado que tengo es siempre 400 Bad Request, y estoy seguro de que los datos que están en las etiquetas son correctos.

Es de hacer constar que el servicio al que intento comunicarme ya se encuentra en funcionamiento, y está en uso, así que tengo claro que el problema está de mi lado.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.-

Comment: Es toda una valentía hacer un SOAP con JavaScript, te recomiendo primero hacer el request con soapUI o alguna herramienta para descartar que los xml's esten perfectos, luego, en cuanto al ajax lo veo bien exepto que yo pondría `text/xml`  como `Content-Type`. También podrías descartar que no exista un problema con el `Authorization`

Comment: Hola! se que pudiste resolver tu duda, yo llego unos años tarde...Pero tengo una duda, qué seria el "action" en el request? De donde sale? Es una funcion o metodo? Es una direccion?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, el error estaba en qué no coloqué los namespaces, y cuando finalmente lo hice, no era la misma versión de soap.  Finalmente el xml quedó así:

```
  `<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelop">
      <s:Header>
           <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IServicioDimoe/ModificarEquipoAInterviniente</a:Action>
           <a:MessageID>${username + (new Date()).getTime()}</a:MessageID>
           <a:ReplyTo>
               <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
           </a:ReplyTo>
           <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://url.com:8443/ServiciosExternos/ServicioDimoe.svc</a:To>
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <ModificarEquipoAInterviniente xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <modificacionRequest>
                     <IdEvento>${id}</IdEvento>
                     <IdDimoe>${caso}</IdDimoe>
                     <Narracion>${narracion}</Narracion>
                     <Documento>
                          <OrigenDocumento>${pais_documento}</OrigenDocumento>
                          <NumeroDocumento>${numero_documento}</NumeroDocumento>
                          <TipoDocumento>${tipo_documento}</TipoDocumento>
                     </Documento>
                     <TobilleraElectronica>
                          <NumeroSerie>${serie}</NumeroSerie>
                          <Linea>0</Linea>
                          <Estado>INACTIVO</Estado>
                          <Observaciones>${observación}</Observaciones>
                     </TobilleraElectronica>
                     <FechaDeEjecucion>${new Date().toISOString()}</FechaDeEjecucion>
                     <Usuario>${usuario}</Usuario>
                </modificacionRequest>
           </ModificarEquipoAInterviniente>
      </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

`

Para el MessageID finalmente utilicé una combinación de nombre de usuario y timestamp.

```
`<a:MessageID>${username + (new Date()).getTime()}</a:MessageID>`
```